# Types of Solitons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

In the condensed matter literature, I have seen broadly two types of solitons which are dark and bright corresponding to fall and rise in density. (I know only the number density case ). But among the dark ones, there are black and grey. And there are probably a few types of bright ones. What are the black and grey solitons and what are the types of bright solitons ? Please explain.

Comment: Some specific links or images can be helpful.

Comment: The only reference I have studied is the paper "Dark Solitons in a superfluid fermi gas" and I googled for the types of solitons etc.. but could not find the meaning of various types.

Comment: is http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0601 the paper?

Comment: @Ali : yes, this is the paper

Comment: hi, i have come to know that Black solitons are ones in which the density dips to zero while the grey solitons are ones in which the density dips but not to zero.

Comment: Then congratulations, you may answer your question yourself!